# How represent message in elgamal elliptic curve Scheme?

Tags: java, algorithm, public-key-encryption, elgamal

I read about elgamal elliptic curve Scheme but I didn't understood how it represent message in this algorithm. If the message m has 128 bit and base point b(x,y) and private key k1 and public key is pub= k1 * b.now Is message m should be is represent in coordinates m(x,y) or not neccessary may be integer number. I need three requests

1. How it represent message in this algorithm.
2. Where I can find code algorithm for standard Elgamal elliptic curve by java.
3. any link explain a bout. How it work..

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_cryptography would be a first starting point.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_encryption is specific to ElGamal. It simply refers to a message m. I presume that any convention that mapped k bits to one of 2^k members of the underlying group would work. The first stage in sending a message is to chose a member of the group at random, with members denoted 1..q-1. Associating the first 2^k of these with k bits of message should work, where k should be as large as possible for efficiency and perhaps security.

Comment: Ok I understand ElGamal_encryption but I need Elgamal Elliptic Curve